# Movie on board a colony ship with cryo pods that look like vacuum seal plastic bags

Tags: story-identification, movie, spaceship

I really only remember one scene so bear with me.

It was a somewhat recent movie about a colony ship, like a thriller/suspense movie I think, there was a few people waking up every few years to do maintenance and check on the sleeping people, but one of them starts sabotaging the crews cryo pods.

The thing that stood out the most to me was the cryo pods were like this vacuum seal plastic bag thing that they didn’t have the parts to fix?

Comment: The plot sounds vaguely like Pandorum (2009) but from what I recall the pods they were suspended in were more conventional chambers and not vacuum sealed bags.

Comment: [Interstellar](https://motherboard-images.vice.com/content-images/contentimage/29716/1453160237898419.png) had something like vaccuum-sealed bags as *part* of the cryogenics system.  There was still a larger machine surrounding and containing that bag though.  Also the stuff about sabotage doesn't really line up (unless maybe you're thinking of *Dr. Mann's* sub-plot.)

Comment: Could it be Passengers with Jennifer Lawrence and Chris Pratt?  I haven't seen it but I know it has people on a spaceship in some kind of suspended animation.